# Разблокировать кнопки при

Tags: javascript, jquery, if

Есть радио кнопки цвета и радио кнопки размера нужна функция которая сравнивает нажатую кнопку цвета с заблокированными кнопками размера и в случае если они равны разблокировать их. Думаю код объяснит лучше меня:
Это кнопки цвета

```
<input type="radio" id="color131" class="color" data-method="#0ff" name="color" value="#0ff">
<input type="radio" id="color131" class="color" data-method="#000040" name="color" value="#000040">
```

Кнопки размера:

```
<input class="radio"  data-option="#0ff" type="radio" value="45" name="option" disabled="">
<input class="radio" data-option="#000040" type="radio" value="39" name="option" disabled="" >
```

Как вы уже поняли нужно сравнить `data-method` и `data-option` и в случае если они равны разблокировать. Написал примитивную функцию, но она не работает вот:

```
$(".color").click(function () {
            var color = $(this).attr("data-method");
            var size = $(".radio").attr("data-option");
            if  (color == size) {
                $('.radio[data-option = '+color+']').prop('disabled', false);
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас проблема в том, что `$(".radio")` возращает **набор** из двух элементов. И когда мы пытаемся взять атрибут из набора, то `jQuery` вернет атрибут первого элемента, который в вашем случае равен **#0ff**.

Посмотрите на этот пример кода. Я думаю, это то, что вам нужно.

```js
$(".color").click(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var color = $this.data("method");
  $('.radio').prop('disabled', true); // выключаем все элементы
  $('.radio[data-option="' + color + '"]').prop('disabled', false); // включаем нужный
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="radio" id="color131" class="color" data-method="#0ff" name="color" value="#0ff">
<input type="radio" id="color131" class="color" data-method="#000040" name="color" value="#000040">

<input class="radio" data-option="#0ff" type="radio" value="45" name="option" disabled="">
<input class="radio" data-option="#000040" type="radio" value="39" name="option" disabled="">
```

Comment: Выдает ошибку `Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .radio[data-option = ...]`

Comment: @AziretKadykeev Это где вам такую ошибку выдает? В снипете все хорошо работает. Возможно, вы не правильно скопировали\переписали код.

Comment: Сниппет? Я скопировал все как есть

Comment: @AziretKadykeev Сниппет - это пример кода, который я привел в ответе. Нажмите на кнопочку **"Выполнить код"**. И вы увидите, как работает код.

Comment: Заработало после того как я изменил версию `jquery`. Почему то на 
версии 3.2.1 выдавало ту ошибку, о которой я писал выше

Comment: @AziretKadykeev можете менять версию обратно на **3.2.1**. Ошибка была в запросе, забыли кавычки мы с вами. Посмотрите ответ, я его поправил.

Answer (score 2):

Еще, как вариант - просто пробежаться по элементам, используя метод `each`:

```js
$('input[name="color"]').click(e => {
  $('input[name="option"]').each((i, opt) => {
    opt.disabled = opt.dataset.option !== e.target.dataset.method;
  }); 
}); 

// то что ниже - чисто для наглядности
$('input').each((i, inp) => {
  let txt = inp.name + ` (${inp.dataset.method || inp.dataset.option || ''})`; 
  $('body').append($('<label/>').append(inp).append(txt)); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="radio" data-method="#0ff" name="color" value="#0ff">
<input type="radio" data-method="#000040" name="color" value="#000040">

<input class="radio"  data-option="#0ff" type="radio" name="option" disabled="">
<input class="radio" data-option="#000040" type="radio" name="option" disabled="">
```

И так как `disabled` является булевым свойством - можно сразу присвоить ему булевый результат неравенства data-атрибутов (с которыми, имхо, гораздо удобнее работать через свойство элемента `dataset`).

---

*p.s.: Тут в качестве коллбэков использованы стрелочные функции, они не поддерживаются IE - если необходима поддержка "осликом", замените их на обычные анонимные функции - `function (e) {...}` и `function (i, opt) {...}`, соответственно.*

Comment: Как быть если `input[name="option"]` равен `data-option="#0ff,#000040"`?

Comment: @Aziret Kadykeev, например, вот так: `opt.disabled = opt.dataset.option.split(/,\s*/).indexOf(e.target.dataset.method) === -1;`. Если слишком длинно, можно разбить на две строки :)